# Django logout problem

Tags: django, authentication

Here is the problem I am facing with the Django Authenetication

1. Access a page that requires a login.
2. Logout (accessing django.contrib.auth.logout)
3. Access the original login-protected page. You are still logged in

Any ideas how to solve the problem?

MY Django Session Settings are

SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 3600

Thanks,
Sujit

Comment: When you say '3. Access the original ...' do you mean 'use the back arrow key and see the cached page image' or do you mean 'clicked on a link to a protected page and it worked when it shouldn't have'?

Comment: Both the cases ... When clicked back button & entering protected page url.

Comment: I added a new question, looks a lot like yours. Solved it yet! see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14021913/django-logout-not-working

Answer (score 2):

Basically, [this should work](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/):

```
from django.contrib.auth import logout

def logout_view(request):
    logout(request)
    # Redirect to a success page.
```

Could you clarify by posting your view if it's not something like this?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

I have the exact code for logout mechanism. 
But still it doesn't logout

Answer (score 1):

In Django 1.4.* I've had problems with the `logout()` function. It simply wasn't logging out my users.

Now I'm just using the contributed view to logout users and it works perfectly. Simply add this to your root `urls.py` file if you don't want to do anything else special:

```
(r'^logout/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout', {'next_page': '/login'}),
```

and you'll be good to go.

Happy Djangoing.

Answer (score 0):

views

from django.contrib.auth import logout

def logout_user(request):

```
"""
    logout the user
"""   

logout(request)
return HttpResponseRedirect('/qioness/connect/')
```

urls:

```
url(r'^userlogout/$',logout_user),
```

worked 4 me

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. I was too stuck with this problem. Found the following solution on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CFypO_LNmcc&t=85s).

My solution is a little modified though.

in views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def auth_logout(request):
  logout(request)
  return redirect('home')
```

in urls.py

```
url(r'^logout$', views.auth_logout, name='auth_logout'),
```

Answer (score 0):

Change session expire on close to False, with true it will not log you out until you close the browser