# Django logout not working

Tags: django, logout

I seem to have the same problem as in this question: [Django logout problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2074980/django-logout-problem)

Mine is a bit weirder, it works in google chrome.... but not in firefox...

this is my logout function: (in views.py)

```
def my_logout(request):
    logger.debug("Logout called by user")
    try:
        # Here I do some custom stuff, like logging this action in a database and so on
        # For this question it shouldn't matter... because in a try catch
        # so whatever goes wrong here, logging out should work anyway
    except Exception, e:
        logger.info("Logging logout action error: %s" % e)
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
```

in settings.py I have:

```
LOGIN_URL = '/desktop/login/'
LOGOUT_URL = '/desktop/logout/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
```

And in the urls.py of the app iamapps (include in the project urls as /desktop/):

```
url(r'^login/$', 'iamapps.views.my_login', name='iamapps.login'),
url(r'^logout/$', 'iamapps.views.my_logout', name='iamapps.logout'),
```

further info:

- django 1.4.3 (just updated from 1.3 to 1.4 ....)
- python 2.7
- works in Chrome but not in Firefox 17.0.1, Linux

The fact that it does work in google chrome but does not work in firefox puzzles me the most. Seems it has something to do with firefox keeps remembering the user as being logged on...

**EDIT:**
I get a broken pipe.... but I seem to get it not on logging out... but going to the home view after logout....

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 86, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 127, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 210, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 268, in send_headers
    self.send_preamble()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 192, in send_preamble
    'Date: %s\r\n' % format_date_time(time.time())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 324, in write
    self.flush()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 303, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 58684)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 582, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 323, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/media/storage/django/sites/iamfloraservice/parts/django/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 139, in __init__
    super(WSGIRequestHandler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 641, in __init__
    self.finish()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 694, in finish
    self.wfile.flush()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 303, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
----------------------------------------
[24/Dec/2012 14:33:25] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 48247
```

**Edit 2**
it goes to this view after loging out and being redirected:

```
def home(request, template='iamfloraservice/home.html'):

    logger.debug("Home view called by user %s" % request.user)
    return render_to_response(template,{},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I think the redirect with the request to this view causes the problem....
In the log sais it's still user 'michel' (beacuse the view uses the request from the redirect, and that had user michel)... however... user michel is being logged out in the mean time....

**EDIT 3**

because of the suggestion it's due to the logger.
unremarking the logging does not help
And it's the default logger:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

**EDIT 4** (30-12-2012)

My logout is from a main window where I show a logout link when a user is logged on and a login link if a user is logged out. Also it contains a toolbar, which tools are filled depending on the the user and it's membership of groups.

I think the problem is, it's reloading this main window while the cache and the user in it's request isn't cleared yet. Somehow Chrome knows how to handle this, and firefox results in a broken pipe error. Clearing the cache manually in the browser results in the correct view after reload....

a solution might be to redirect to a page without anything in it that contains users...
or find out to clear the cache on the right moment myselve....

this problem describes maybe the same... but I cannot expect users to do anything in the browser just to logout? see [django 1.4 caching GET to /login/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10903809/django-1-4-caching-get-to-login)

**Edit 5** (31-12-2012)

It seems it's a caching problem.... but not sure how to fix this yet.

these are my caching settings:

```
if not DEBUG:
    CACHES = {
        'default': {
            'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
            'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:11211',
        }
    }
else:
    CACHES = {
        'default': {
            'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.dummy.DummyCache',
        }
    }
```

But I tried without the dummycache as well

**EDIT 6** (4-jan-2013)
Still no solution.... I changed the way I log out to the django way, and I Am using the signals now... see my own answer below.

but still it gives the brokenpipe error which causes firefox stopping logging out. It's not a caching problem. If I go to another page, or even worse... the admin pages. I Am still logged on. The only way to logout is through the logout on the admin page.... If it's not an admin user... there is no way to get me logged out on the firefox browser.

When logging off using the admin interface, so the signal works fine...

I checked by turning off the signal.... and still the logging out in firefox does not work.

Conclusion: going back to the main page () is causing the problem.

**EDIT 7** (4 jan 2013)
I made a simple loggedout view for testing,
this template:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
Logged out
</title>
</head>
<body>
You are succesfully logged out.<br>
<br>
<a href="/">Go back to the main page</a>
or<br>
<a href="/desktop/login/?next=/">log in again</a>
</body>
</html>
```

and the logged out view:

```
class LoggedOutView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "iamapps/logged_out.html"
```

and changed the urls in to:

```
url(r'^logout/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout',  {'next_page': '/desktop/loggedout/'}, name='iamapps.logout'),
#url(r'^logout/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout_then_login',  name='iamapps.logout'),
url(r'^loggedout/$', LoggedOutView.as_view(),name='iamapps.loggedout'),
```

and still, to simplyfy things... I have the signals turned off.

and it's still not working in firefox.... but it works in chrome

In firefox it does not go to the logged out page

Comment: do you receive any error when you call logout?

Comment: @AamirAdnan: Thanx, I forgot to mention that one...

Comment: I think the problem is with your logger. Can you please test the `my_logout` view without logging any information, instead use `print` statements.

Comment: Thanks for your time, but this is the default django logger. I placed a remark sign before it, did not help.

Comment: What happens in the browser? Are you redirected to the `/` but remain logged in? In this case can the home page be cached?

Comment: I get redirected, but still seems to be logged on. Even if I go to another page, which requires being logged on.... I Am still logged on. Even the admin pages. Logging off through the admin pages works fine... but this is not using my custom logout view

Comment: but it has something to do with caching, if i go to firefox preferences and clear all current history. and refresh the browser... its logged out! However, logging on and off again.... the same problem. How can I change this behaviour from django?

Comment: Could it be caching issue? That what you see are cached pages?

Comment: @Evgeny: I Am pretty sure it's a caching problem now.... but how to regulate this the same for firefox as for chrome?

Comment: If you have the same issue when running django runserver, then maybe django caching setup has some issues. Otherwise it could be due to your production webserver setting some caching related headers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to configure where to redirect after a log out in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5315100/how-to-configure-where-to-redirect-after-a-log-out-in-django)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I totally switched to almost back to django defaults...
Using:

in views.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView

class LoginView(FormView):
    """
    This is a class based version of django.contrib.auth.views.login.


    """
    form_class = AuthenticationForm
    redirect_field_name = REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME
    template_name = 'iamapps/login.html'


    @method_decorator(csrf_protect)
    @method_decorator(never_cache)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(LoginView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        """
        The user has provided valid credentials (this was checked in AuthenticationForm.is_valid()). So now we
        can check the test cookie stuff and log him in.
        """
        self.check_and_delete_test_cookie()
        login(self.request, form.get_user())
        return super(LoginView, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(LoginView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        apps_settings=iamapps_settings()
        if apps_settings[LOGON_BASE_APP_NAME]:
            self.extend_template="%s/base.html" % apps_settings[LOGON_BASE_APP_NAME]
        else:
            self.extend_template="iamapps/base.html"
        context['extend_template']=self.extend_template
        return context    

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        """
        The user has provided invalid credentials (this was checked in AuthenticationForm.is_valid()). So now we
        set the test cookie again and re-render the form with errors.
        """
        self.set_test_cookie()
        return super(LoginView, self).form_invalid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        if self.success_url:
            redirect_to = self.success_url
        else:
            redirect_to = self.request.REQUEST.get(self.redirect_field_name, '')

        netloc = urlparse.urlparse(redirect_to)[1]
        if not redirect_to:
            redirect_to = settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL
        # Security check -- don't allow redirection to a different host.
        elif netloc and netloc != self.request.get_host():
            redirect_to = settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL
        return redirect_to

    def set_test_cookie(self):
        self.request.session.set_test_cookie()

    def check_and_delete_test_cookie(self):
        if self.request.session.test_cookie_worked():
            self.request.session.delete_test_cookie()
            return True
        return False

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Same as django.views.generic.edit.ProcessFormView.get(), but adds test cookie stuff
        """
        self.set_test_cookie()
        return super(LoginView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

and urls:

```
url(r'^login/$', LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
```

This solved all my troubles... about loggin and logiing off on...

the login and logout signals just working fine:

```
from django.contrib.auth.signals import user_logged_out, user_logged_in

# Note, these login and logout signals are registered in imamstats views
def iam_logged_out_actions(sender, user, request, **kwargs):
    try:
        # ... do my logging out actiosn (stats etc.)
    except Exception, e:
        logger.error("Logging logout action error: %s" % e)

# Note, these login and logout signals are registered in imamstats views
def iam_logged_in_actions(sender, user, request, **kwargs):
    try:
        # ... do my log in stats etc. things
    except Exception, e:
        logger.error("Logging login action error: %s" % e)
```

Answer (score 14):

I generally just use the contributed view to logout users. Simply add this to your root `urls.py` file:

```
# Would be nice to use settings.LOGIN_URL for `next_page` here, too
url(r'^logout/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout', {'next_page': '/login'}),
```

and you'll be good to go.

Happy Djangoing.

Comment: First of all thank you for your time during christmas! (Merry christmas to you and all). It supports me enormously to see I Am not the only one with this issue. However, using your suggestion, I cannot do my custom stuff anymore... and that would be giving up.... and that's not happy djangoing to me :)

Comment: I will give you some points... see my answer... your answer is part of the solution.... adding signals does the rest.

Comment: by the way, why not use logout_than_login ... see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.views

Comment: Struggling quite some time to use url(r'^logout', views.logout, name='logout') to call the logout(request), but I failed. Thanks very much for this clean solution

Answer (score 2):

browsing to stackoverflow... (did another search)

I found this one: .... see [django.contrib.auth.logout in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11241080/django-contrib-auth-logout-in-django) ..

But is is even worse.... I found this... astonished... but explains it all:
[Django, Logout_URL doesn't redirect well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11933361/django-logout-url-doesnt-redirect-well)

The I found out it's a won't fix bug (@##$%%) not allowed to curse on christmas eve....

So the solution to do my custom stuff is in the signals in stead of using my own view.
Do the default view and redirect...
and use this documentation to create a signal.. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#login-and-logout-signals

Adding the signals is quite easy, i put it in models.py off my main app (iamapps):

```
import logging
from django.contrib.auth.signals import user_logged_out
from django.contrib.auth.signals import user_logged_in
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def iam_logged_out_actions(sender, user, request, **kwargs):
    #whatever...
    logger.debug("Logging out: user = %s" % user)

user_logged_out.connect(iam_logged_out_actions)

def iam_logged_in_actions(sender, user, request, **kwargs):
    #whatever...
    logger.debug("Logging in: user = %s" % user)

user_logged_in.connect(iam_logged_in_actions)
```

This works....however it does not solve the broken pipe which I think might cause the failure on the logging out... so logging out in firefox still fails... and in chrome it works...
Logging out from django admin page works in firefox.. and the signal has another pro: also from logging out in the admin interface, the signal is being called...

for logging out i use now this urls.py:

```
    url(r'^logout/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout',  {'next_page': '/'}, name='iamapps.logout'),
```

Answer (score 1):

My suspicion is that the original logout view returns a response that clears cookie or something like that, and you're throwing that response out. Could you try simply returning its response to the user, like this?

```
def my_logout(request):
    # something...
    return logout(request)
```

Comment: This won't help. Its giving an error "The view iamapps.views.iam_logout didn't return an HttpResponse object." But it learned me something new. Firefox won't even get there.... only chrome gives this error...

Comment: @michel.iamit: Other thoughts: 1) your "something" may do `return` with something weird; 2) you're not importing/using correct generic logout view; 3) generic logout view is somehow b0rked or thrown off

Comment: I changed the way I logged out completely, and using the generic logout, see my answer here above. And I Am using the signals now. In the signal I save something to the database, in which I use the user from the request.... and still it does not work.... it seems the logout procedure does not wait for the signal to be processed...

Answer (score 1):

The verified answer work well for the mentioned version but it is not working in django 2.2 version any more. so in order to do successful redirect after logout you have to define the attributes.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from dark_bot import views
from django.contrib.auth import views as v
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.index, name="index"),
    path('contact/', views.contact, name="contact"),
    path('search/', include('search.urls')),
    path('user/', include('accounts.urls')),
    path('dashboard/', include('dashboard.urls')),
    path('accounts/login/', v.LoginView.as_view(), name="login"),
    path('accounts/logout/',v.LogoutView.as_view(next_page='/'),name="logout")
    # path('dashboard/', include('dashboard.urls')),
]
```

This is how you can see I passed the next_page attribute to the class LogoutView which will tell where to redirect or go after successfull logout.
Hope this may help someone.
Happy Coding!